How to Configure a PID controller Yaml file in ROS2_Control
In this page of the documentation of ros2 control There is no mention of how to make the PID controller actually work. If I run the yaml file example provided
test_pid_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    dof_names:
      - joint1

    command_interface: position

    reference_and_state_interfaces: ["position"]

    gains:
      joint1: {p: 1.0, i: 2.0, d: 10.0, i_clamp_max: 5.0, i_clamp_min: -5.0}

I  get a no 'type' param was provided error
I modified the yaml file to be as follow:
controller_manager:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 100 # Hz

    joint_state_broadcaster:
      type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster

    test_pid_controller:
      type: pid_controllers/MyController #I tried anything because no info. provided

test_pid_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    dof_names:
      - joint0

    command_interface: effort

    reference_and_state_interfaces: ["effort"]

    gains:
      joint0: {p: 1.0, i: 2.0, d: 10.0, i_clamp_max: 5.0, i_clamp_min: -5.0}

and the launch file as:

from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch.conditions import IfCondition
from launch.substitutions import Command, FindExecutable, LaunchConfiguration, PathJoinSubstitution
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch_ros.substitutions import FindPackageShare


def generate_launch_description():
    declared_arguments = []

    declared_arguments.append(
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            "joint0_controller",
            default_value="test_pid_controller",
        )
    )

  
    joint0_controller = LaunchConfiguration("joint0_controller")


    robot_description_content = Command(
        [
            PathJoinSubstitution([FindExecutable(name="xacro")]),
            " ",
            PathJoinSubstitution(
                [
                    FindPackageShare("odrive_demo_description"),
                    "urdf",
                    "odrive.urdf.xacro",
                ]
            ),
        
        ]
    )
    robot_description = {"robot_description": robot_description_content}

    robot_controllers = PathJoinSubstitution(
        [
            FindPackageShare("odrive_demo_bringup"),
            "config",
            "odrive_multi_interface_forward_controllers.yaml",
        ]
    )

    control_node = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="ros2_control_node",
        output="both",
        parameters=[robot_description, robot_controllers],
    )

    robot_state_pub_node = Node(
        package="robot_state_publisher",
        executable="robot_state_publisher",
        output="both",
        parameters=[robot_description],
    )

    joint_state_broadcaster_spawner = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner",
        arguments=["joint_state_broadcaster", "-c", "/controller_manager"],
    )

    joint0_controller_spawner = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner",
        arguments=[joint0_controller, "-c", "/controller_manager"],
        condition=IfCondition(enable_joint0),
    )

  

    nodes = [
        control_node,
        robot_state_pub_node,
        joint_state_broadcaster_spawner,
        joint0_controller_spawner,
    
    ]

    return LaunchDescription(declared_arguments + nodes)


The error I get is this:
 Loader for controller 'test_pid_controller' (type 'pid_controllers/MyController') not found.
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1716809582.226275154] [controller_manager]: Available classes:
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1716809582.226280982] [controller_manager]:   controller_manager/test_controller
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1716809582.226284774] [controller_manager]:   controller_manager/test_controller_failed_init
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1716809582.226288265] [controller_manager]:   controller_manager/test_controller_with_interfaces
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1716809582.226291837] [controller_manager]:   diff_drive_controller/DiffDriveController
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1716809582.226295379] [controller_manager]:   effort_controllers/JointGroupEffortController
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1716809582.226298651] [controller_manager]:   force_torque_sensor_broadcaster/ForceTorqueSensorBroadcaster
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1716809582.226302046] [controller_manager]:   forward_command_controller/ForwardCommandController
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1716809582.226305513] [controller_manager]:   forward_command_controller/MultiInterfaceForwardCommandController
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1716809582.226309029] [controller_manager]:   imu_sensor_broadcaster/IMUSensorBroadcaster
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1716809582.226312409] [controller_manager]:   joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1716809582.226315616] [controller_manager]:   joint_trajectory_controller/JointTrajectoryController
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1716809582.226318992] [controller_manager]:   position_controllers/JointGroupPositionController
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1716809582.226322531] [controller_manager]:   range_sensor_broadcaster/RangeSensorBroadcaster
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1716809582.226325760] [controller_manager]:   tricycle_controller/TricycleController
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1716809582.226329079] [controller_manager]:   velocity_controllers/JointGroupVelocityController
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1716809582.226333573] [controller_manager]:   ackermann_steering_controller/AckermannSteeringController
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1716809582.226339461] [controller_manager]:   admittance_controller/AdmittanceController
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1716809582.226343049] [controller_manager]:   bicycle_steering_controller/BicycleSteeringController
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1716809582.226346316] [controller_manager]:   controller_manager/test_chainable_controller
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1716809582.226349625] [controller_manager]:   tricycle_steering_controller/TricycleSteeringController

I installed control-toolbox using apt but still no use.
I know the issue is with the type of the controller, what is the correct type?

See this section: You have to use type: pid_controller/PidController. (I have to admit, this could be documented clearer).
controller_manager:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 10  # Hz

    test_pid_controller:
        type: pid_controller/PidController

test_pid_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    dof_names:
      - joint0
    <etc>

Since a recent change we also support a configuration like
controller_manager:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 10  # Hz

test_pid_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    type: pid_controller/PidController
    dof_names:
      - joint0
    <etc>


Thanks a lot Christopher, I tried type: pid_controller/PidController but I still got the same error from the control manger [ros2_control_node-1] [ERROR] [1716872181.723049299] [controller_manager]: Loader for controller 'test_pid_controller' (type 'pid_controller/PidController') not found. Am I launching it correctly? Do I need to install something else?

It seems that it is not installed (from your console output in the original question). If you install sudo apt-get install ros-$ROS_DISTRO-ros2-controllersit should be installed. Which distro are you using? PID Controller is only available for Jazzy+Rolling.

I'm using humble, that is why. I will update to Jazzy and test it again. Thank you Christopher.
